# Android Project works fine on physical device but fails when run by google playstore prelease/robotest

Tags: android

I am totally stuck... I don't know what to do.

Spent 6 months developing an App. Finally went to the play store uploaded my release and it crashes when run on Google Playstore Pre Release. Really don't know why. BTW the test was run by google on Pixel 3 .

I re ran the test in Firebase RoboTest (also in Pixel 3) still the problem persists.
First I thought it was something to do with the TelephonyManager, I removed all reference to it but it still fails.

The error is as follows:

[image]

Here are the logs

```
11-01 18:26:47.603: I/ActivityManager(1162): Killing 

22547:com.google.process.gapps/u0a7 (adj 906): empty #17
11-01 18:26:47.603: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22547, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.604: I/Finsky(22460): [311] jrk.b(5): Removing listener for user UserHandle{0} and listener 158987678
11-01 18:26:47.611: I/ActivityManager(1162): Killing 22164:com.google.intelligence.sense/u0a31 (adj 906): empty #17
11-01 18:26:47.620: I/Finsky(22460): [2] yeh.d(13): PackageMonitorReceiverImpl - Received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED, [OwTLqO6btGsi6Tcv2-TznXK21v3lwAbORH4jydMacKQ]
11-01 18:26:47.620: I/Finsky(22460): [2] yfi.g(1): Invalidating cached PackageState for androidx.test.tools.crawler
11-01 18:26:47.622: I/Finsky(22460): [2] yfi.p(3): Package no longer installed: androidx.test.tools.crawler
11-01 18:26:47.624: I/Finsky(22460): [296] ovz.run(16): Frosting DB delete succeeded: false
11-01 18:26:47.625: I/Finsky(22460): [2] yeh.d(16): PackageMonitorReceiverImpl - Deduping intent android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED
11-01 18:26:47.641: I/ActivityManager(1162): Force stopping com.vlix.contacts appid=10171 user=0: pkg removed
11-01 18:26:47.648: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22547, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.655: I/Finsky(22460): [2] yeh.d(13): PackageMonitorReceiverImpl - Received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED, [L5Vw54j97Bg4DBgBl5WDdiEpCgW-IVJRJhs3mjRzR9o]
11-01 18:26:47.655: I/Finsky(22460): [2] yfi.g(1): Invalidating cached PackageState for com.vlix.contacts
11-01 18:26:47.655: I/InputReader(1162): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
11-01 18:26:47.656: I/ConditionProviders(1162): Disallowing condition provider com.vlix.contacts
11-01 18:26:47.658: E/PackageManager(1162): failed to find package com.vlix.contacts
11-01 18:26:47.658: E/OverlayManager(1162): Failed to change enabled overlays for com.vlix.contacts user 0
11-01 18:26:47.658: I/ActivityManager(1162): Start proc 28803:com.google.android.apps.wellbeing/u0a26 for broadcast com.google.android.apps.wellbeing/.appusage.impl.AppUsagePackageFullyRemovedBroadcastReceiver_Receiver
11-01 18:26:47.658: I/Finsky(22460): [2] yfi.p(3): Package no longer installed: com.vlix.contacts
11-01 18:26:47.665: D/WifiConfigManager(1162): Remove all networks for app ApplicationInfo{433f31d com.vlix.contacts}
11-01 18:26:47.667: I/Finsky(22460): [296] ovz.run(16): Frosting DB delete succeeded: true
11-01 18:26:47.667: E/.apps.wellbein(28803): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
11-01 18:26:47.668: I/Finsky(22460): [2] qnq.s(2): Installer: package com.vlix.contacts was removed. replacing: false
11-01 18:26:47.669: I/Finsky(22460): [2] qoo.L(12): Installer: Notifying status update. package=com.vlix.contacts, status=UNINSTALLED
11-01 18:26:47.671: I/Finsky(22460): [2] amas.a(3): Do not start WearSupportService due to Wear service optimization
11-01 18:26:47.675: I/Zygote(731): Process 22164 exited due to signal (9)
11-01 18:26:47.675: D/RegisteredNfcFServicesCache(4195): Service unchanged, not updating
11-01 18:26:47.676: I/Finsky(22460): [297] jnw.a(15): [ContentSync] finished, scheduled=false
11-01 18:26:47.677: I/Finsky(22460): [2] amas.a(3): Do not start WearSupportService due to Wear service optimization
11-01 18:26:47.681: I/Zygote(731): Process 22547 exited due to signal (9)
11-01 18:26:47.683: I/Finsky(22460): [298] gxq.a(12): Asset module storage cleared for package com.vlix.contacts.
11-01 18:26:47.683: I/Finsky(22460): [2] aeak.a(8): Clearing split related stale data.
11-01 18:26:47.685: E/PhoneInterfaceManager(3800): [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
11-01 18:26:47.685: D/CarrierSvcBindHelper(3800): No carrier app for: 0
11-01 18:26:47.685: I/Finsky(22460): [2] yfi.p(3): Package no longer installed: com.vlix.contacts
11-01 18:26:47.686: I/Finsky(22460): [296] ovz.run(16): Frosting DB delete succeeded: false
11-01 18:26:47.688: D/ExternalStorage(28784): After updating volumes, found 2 active roots
11-01 18:26:47.692: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22547, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.692: I/libprocessgroup(1162): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10007 pid 22547 in 89ms
11-01 18:26:47.692: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22164, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.692: I/libprocessgroup(1162): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10031 pid 22164 in 0ms
11-01 18:26:47.697: W/Finsky(22460): [306] qzt.call(45): Cannot find installStatus. Using status from installer: status=# qso@faab3a36
11-01 18:26:47.698: I/Finsky(22460): [306] rcb.C(2): IQ: Notifying installation update. package=com.vlix.contacts, status=UNINSTALLED
11-01 18:26:47.700: I/Fitness(11058): FitCleanupIntentOperation received Intent android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED [CONTEXT service_id=17 ]
11-01 18:26:47.700: I/Finsky(22460): [2] qoo.O(7): Installer: found apps to install. isMultiUserMode=false, apps=[]
11-01 18:26:47.716: I/.apps.wellbein(28803): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
11-01 18:26:47.729: I/GmsCoreXrpcWrapper(14565): Returning a channel provider with trafficStatsTag=12803 trafficStatsUid=-1
11-01 18:26:47.732: I/ActivityManager(1162): Start proc 28826:com.android.mtp/u0a8 for content provider com.android.mtp/.MtpDocumentsProvider
11-01 18:26:47.738: E/com.android.mt(28826): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
11-01 18:26:47.745: W/DriveInitializer(14565): Awaiting to be initialized
11-01 18:26:47.752: I/ActivityManager(1162): Killing 21662:com.google.android.apps.messaging/u0a111 (adj 906): empty #17
11-01 18:26:47.753: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-21662, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.757: I/Finsky(22460): [306] rcb.t(33): IQ: No matching installs to run for jobs: []
11-01 18:26:47.759: I/Icing(14565): Usage reports ok 0, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0
11-01 18:26:47.762: I/Icing(14565): Indexing com.google.android.gms-apps from com.google.android.gms
11-01 18:26:47.767: I/Icing(14565): Indexing done com.google.android.gms-apps
11-01 18:26:47.768: I/Icing(14565): IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.gms componentName=null serviceId=30
11-01 18:26:47.782: I/BlockstoreStorage(14565): Clearing all the Blockstore Data for package com.vlix.contacts [CONTEXT service_id=258 ]
11-01 18:26:47.783: I/BlockstoreStorage(14565): Clearing all the Blockstore Data for 1 packages [CONTEXT service_id=258 ]
11-01 18:26:47.792: I/GmsCoreXrpcWrapper(14565): Returning a channel provider with trafficStatsTag=12803 trafficStatsUid=-1
11-01 18:26:47.798: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-21662, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.801: D/AndroidRuntime(28819): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
11-01 18:26:47.803: I/ContentMaintenance(14565): Internal cache bytes used: 0; limit: 100000000; download size: 0
11-01 18:26:47.809: I/PinnedContentDownloader(14565): Finished downloading pinned content.
11-01 18:26:47.812: I/RealtimeCacheCleanup(14565): Beginning Realtime garbage collection.
11-01 18:26:47.812: I/Icing(14565): Usage reports ok 0, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0
11-01 18:26:47.813: I/Icing(14565): doRemovePackageData com.vlix.contacts
11-01 18:26:47.813: I/RealtimeCacheCleanup(14565): Finished Realtime garbage collection.
11-01 18:26:47.822: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-21662, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.828: I/Icing(14565): Indexing com.google.android.gms-apps from com.google.android.gms
11-01 18:26:47.832: I/Icing(14565): Indexing done com.google.android.gms-apps
11-01 18:26:47.834: I/Zygote(731): Process 21662 exited due to signal (9)
11-01 18:26:47.837: D/BoundBrokerSvc(14565): onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.walletp2p.service.firstparty.BIND pkg=com.google.android.gms }
11-01 18:26:47.857: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-21662, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.857: I/libprocessgroup(1162): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10111 pid 21662 in 103ms
11-01 18:26:47.862: D/BoundBrokerSvc(11058): onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.scheduler.ACTION_PROXY_SCHEDULE cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentInternalBoundBrokerService }
11-01 18:26:47.862: D/BoundBrokerSvc(11058): Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.scheduler.ACTION_PROXY_SCHEDULE cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentInternalBoundBrokerService }
11-01 18:26:47.881: I/app_process(28819): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
11-01 18:26:47.898: I/gle.android.gm(14565): Compiler allocated 5MB to compile void adjr.P(com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.EventParcel, com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMetadata)
11-01 18:26:47.903: D/AndroidRuntime(28819): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-01 18:26:47.907: I/ActivityManager(1162): Force stopping com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil appid=10155 user=0: start instr
11-01 18:26:47.919: I/ActivityManager(1162): Start proc 28860:com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil/u0a155 for added application com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil
11-01 18:26:47.919: E/mtaas.loginuti(28860): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
11-01 18:26:47.932: I/ActivityManager(1162): Start proc 28873:com.android.shell/2000 for content provider com.android.shell/.BugreportStorageProvider
11-01 18:26:47.933: E/m.android.shel(28873): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
11-01 18:26:47.936: I/mtaas.loginuti(28860): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
11-01 18:26:47.940: I/ActivityManager(1162): Killing 22077:com.google.android.contacts/u0a90 (adj 906): empty #17
11-01 18:26:47.941: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22077, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.955: D/LoginUtil(28860): Removing Account {name=HX6BD5S7P6SE6J3T4PXOOTVBHU-01@cloudtestlabaccounts.com, type=com.google}
11-01 18:26:47.966: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22077, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:47.967: I/Zygote(731): Process 22077 exited due to signal (9)
11-01 18:26:47.968: I/ActivityManager(1162): Start proc 28889:com.google.android.apps.auth.test.support/u0a157 for service com.google.android.apps.auth.test.support/.services.AccountService
11-01 18:26:47.970: E/th.test.suppor(28889): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
11-01 18:26:47.985: I/th.test.suppor(28889): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
11-01 18:26:48.008: E/ActivityThread(28889): Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.common.testing.services.storage.testargs
11-01 18:26:48.008: W/AuthService(28889): [TestArgsHelper] Error when calling AndroidTestUtil.getTestArgs(). Note that this behavior might be expected.
11-01 18:26:48.012: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22077, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.012: I/libprocessgroup(1162): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10090 pid 22077 in 70ms
11-01 18:26:48.017: I/ActivityManager(1162): Start proc 28906:com.google.android.apps.docs/u0a128 for content provider com.google.android.apps.docs/.storagebackend.StorageBackendContentProvider
11-01 18:26:48.017: E/droid.apps.doc(28906): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
11-01 18:26:48.026: I/ActivityManager(1162): Killing 23448:com.android.vending:instant_app_installer/u0a14 (adj 906): empty #17
11-01 18:26:48.026: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-23448, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.032: I/AuthService(28889): [RemoveAccountOperation] Removing account: Account {name=HX6BD5S7P6SE6J3T4PXOOTVBHU-01@cloudtestlabaccounts.com, type=com.google}.
11-01 18:26:48.038: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-23448, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.046: I/AccountManagerService(1162): the accounts changed, sending broadcast of android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED
11-01 18:26:48.052: D/ConnectivityService(1162): ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=71, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10014] ], android.os.BinderProxy@16f22f9)
11-01 18:26:48.052: D/ConnectivityService(1162): ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=72, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10014] ], android.os.BinderProxy@e8ff23e)
11-01 18:26:48.053: D/ConnectivityService(1162): releasing NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=71, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10014] ] (release request)
11-01 18:26:48.053: I/Zygote(732): Process 23448 exited due to signal (9)
11-01 18:26:48.054: D/BoundBrokerSvc(11058): onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.instantapps.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
11-01 18:26:48.060: I/AuthService(28889): [AccountService] Execution time for remove account is 49 ms.
11-01 18:26:48.060: I/droid.apps.doc(28906): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
11-01 18:26:48.062: D/LoginUtil(28860): Instrumentation completed successfully
11-01 18:26:48.062: I/ActivityManager(1162): Force stopping com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil appid=10155 user=0: finished inst
11-01 18:26:48.062: I/ActivityManager(1162): Killing 28860:com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil/u0a155 (adj 0): stop com.google.android.apps.mtaas.loginutil
11-01 18:26:48.063: W/Binder(1162): Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
11-01 18:26:48.063: W/Binder(1162): java.lang.Throwable
11-01 18:26:48.063: W/Binder(1162):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1116)
11-01 18:26:48.063: W/Binder(1162):     at android.app.IInstrumentationWatcher$Stub$Proxy.instrumentationFinished(IInstrumentationWatcher.java:164)
11-01 18:26:48.063: W/Binder(1162):     at com.android.server.am.InstrumentationReporter$MyThread.run(InstrumentationReporter.java:86)
11-01 18:26:48.065: D/AndroidRuntime(28819): Shutting down VM
11-01 18:26:48.068: D/fpc_hidl(28920): fpc fingerprint hwbinder service starting
11-01 18:26:48.068: D/QSEECOMAPI(28920): QSEECom_get_handle sb_length = 0x80
11-01 18:26:48.068: D/QSEECOMAPI(28920): App is not loaded in QSEE
11-01 18:26:48.068: D/QSEECOMAPI(28920): app_arch = 2, total_files = 9
11-01 18:26:48.070: I/ActivityManager(1162): Killing 22756:com.android.vending:download_service/u0a14 (adj 906): empty #17
11-01 18:26:48.071: I/Zygote(731): Process 28860 exited due to signal (9)
11-01 18:26:48.081: I/Icing(14565): updateResources: need to parse zml{com.google.android.gms}
11-01 18:26:48.083: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-23448, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.083: I/libprocessgroup(1162): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10014 pid 23448 in 57ms
11-01 18:26:48.084: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-28860, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.084: I/libprocessgroup(1162): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10155 pid 28860 in 0ms
11-01 18:26:48.084: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22756, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.094: I/ContactsProvider(17701): Accounts changed
11-01 18:26:48.104: I/Icing(14565): doRemovePackageData com.google.android.videos
11-01 18:26:48.105: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22756, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.106: I/MultiDex(28803): VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
11-01 18:26:48.106: I/MultiDex(28803): install
11-01 18:26:48.106: I/MultiDex(28803): VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
11-01 18:26:48.110: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22756, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.124: D/QSEECOMAPI(28920): Loaded image: APP id = 217
11-01 18:26:48.129: W/EventHub(1162): Unable to disable kernel key repeat for /dev/input/event3: Function not implemented
11-01 18:26:48.129: I/EventHub(1162): wakeMechanism=EPOLLWAKEUP, usingClockIoctl=true
11-01 18:26:48.129: I/EventHub(1162): New device: id=217, fd=304, path='/dev/input/event3', name='uinput-fpc', classes=0x101, configuration='/system/usr/idc/uinput-fpc.idc', keyLayout='/system/usr/keylayout/uinput-fpc.kl', keyCharacterMap='/system/usr/keychars/Generic.kcm', builtinKeyboard=true, 
11-01 18:26:48.129: W/InputReader(1162): Ignoring spurious device added event for deviceId 0.
11-01 18:26:48.129: E/fpc_tac(28920): fpcbuildinfo : 575ddab5b91efea67ee1d200fc813ff2fpc_bio=bd35c3fec78219829149bea6c9ec961e6f655b90C:prodtestlib=4304cf5c884c198624b749af3482befacbd3028eC:fpc_c_core=dc194509594e837dedfb5452aaf06fcb61977135C:fpc_lib=cd5b7b876c3d69afa68a11ac6fd86f873e70817bC:cac=297e11552c60a3607ed664cf44c3e4b36ab2e737C:fpc_bio_interface=94a457caecae31eca8ef04b64c3f82a018e9bbc0C:fpc_sensor=ba909a5500944acafe47a0ef3a49f89509aadfb6C:tools_core=94ddf1e684cfa6c99f0f237f7cc35f3962e0e597C:sensor_settings=4fcf864fb493ae0272a9b2806446b379d99fd8ceC:fingerprint_ta=066bc0ab880960a4a69b74a328c7d7871c72225bC:fingerprint_pal=0deb9a478a3572872639f9cb2559ccc464ee3f9bC:manifests=dcb3d8ab0bdb7a5b341839d8c75bb88fc7f5e1a4C:Manifesttag=SW23.3.0-PDR1.0.5:jenkins@84ffd74dac44:Thu,17May201810:17:08+0200:FPC_SENSOR_TYPE=FPC_SENSOR_TYPE_FPC1270:FPC_CC_TYPE=FPC_COMPANION_CHIP_FPC2050:FPC_C_TYPE=FPC_COATING_NORMAL
11-01 18:26:48.129: E/fpc_tac(28920): fpcbuildtype : build=RELEASE sensor=9
11-01 18:26:48.133: W/Icing(14565): Package com.android.chrome targets Android P and isn't allowed to use AppDataSearch indexing API
11-01 18:26:48.135: W/Icing(14565): Package com.google.android.gm targets Android P and isn't allowed to use AppDataSearch indexing API
11-01 18:26:48.140: W/Icing(14565): Package com.google.android.music targets Android P and isn't allowed to use AppDataSearch indexing API
11-01 18:26:48.155: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22756, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.170: D/ConnectivityService(1162): ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=70, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10014] ], android.os.BinderProxy@917af44)
11-01 18:26:48.171: D/ConnectivityService(1162): releasing NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=70, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10014] ] (release request)
11-01 18:26:48.167: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22756, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.171: I/Zygote(732): Process 22756 exited due to signal (9)
11-01 18:26:48.187: W/libprocessgroup(1162): kill(-22756, 9) failed: No such process
11-01 18:26:48.187: I/libprocessgroup(1162): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10014 pid 22756 in 103ms
11-01 18:26:48.204: I/ContactsProvider(17701): Accounts changed
```

I know it's hard to troubleshoot but can someone point me what to do? Any advice is appreciated! I am totally blind.

Is there a google support that can help?

Thanks